# Regex which will return a group only if a certain word exists

Tags: regex

I currently have a regex which works fine for certain type of input.

Reg Ex: `(.*)\s*PER\s*([^\s]+).*`

**Sample Input 1** : 1.0 PER Sample DEAD VOLUME 1

**Output:**

Matching Group 1 : **1.0**

Matching Group 2 : **Sample**

**Sample Input 2** : 1.0 PER Request DEAD VOLUME 1

**Output:**

Matching Group 1 : **1.0**

Matching Group 2 : **Request**

Now i need to modify the regex to also work for inputs like below.

**Input 1** : 10.0 PER Empty Well In Column DEAD VOLUME 10

**Expected Output**:

Matching Group 1 : **10.0**

Matching Group 2 : **Empty Well**

Matching Group 3 : **Column**

**Input 2** : 8.0 PER Empty Well In Row DEAD VOLUME 8

**Expected Output**:

Matching Group 1 : **8.0**

Matching Group 2 : **Empty Well**

Matching Group 3 : **Row**

I have found a reg ex which processes the second type of inputs successfully.

RegEx: `(.*)\s*PER\s*(.*)\s*In\s*(.*)\s*DEAD\s*.*`

**Is there way i can make a regex which will work for both these type of inputs**

**UPDATE:**

Hi Just need one more help...I forgot to mention one more condition...This reg also needs to work for the below inputs.

1. **1.0 PER Sample**
2. **1.0 PER Request**
3. **10.0 PER Empty Well In Column**

Meaning the DEAD VOLUME portion is an optional one.

Is this possible too????

Comment: Are these the only key words you are trying to match? Request, Sample and Empty Well?

Comment: Add "Batch" and "Plate" to that list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an optional group with dot lazy matching:

```
^([\d.]+)\s+PER\s+(.*?)(?:\sIn\s*(.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aM7kL6/10)

Matches:

```
1.0 PER Sample DEAD VOLUME 1
   1.0
   Sample

1.0 PER Request DEAD VOLUME 1
   1.0
   Request

10.0 PER Empty Well In Column DEAD VOLUME 10
   10.0
   Empty Well
   Column

8.0 PER Empty Well In Row DEAD VOLUME 8
   8.0
   Empty Well
   Row
```

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 1 capturing any 1+ digits or dots
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `PER` - a literal text `PER`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?:\sIn\s*(.+?))?`  - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `\sIn` - a whitespace followed with `In` text
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(.+?)` - Group 3 capturing one or more chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?:\s*DEAD.*)?` - an optional group matching:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `DEAD` -  a literal text `DEAD`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline up to
  - `$` - the end of string (`$`).

Comment: Hi Just need one more help...I forgot to mention one more condition...Just have a look at the updated portion in the question and kindly help me resolve this...

Comment: Let me see. The point is that an optional group after `.*` or `.*?` should be "anchored" to an obligatory pattern, or it will be "garbled" by the dot. Try [`^(.*?)\s*PER\s*((?:(?!\s(?:In|DEAD)).)*)(?:\sIn\s*(.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/aM7kL6/8)

Comment: Or a simpler one: [`^([\d.]+)\s+PER\s+(.*?)(?:\sIn\s*(.+?))?(?:\s*DEAD.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/aM7kL6/10)